# IBM MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 Cordova starter application crashes in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to test the MFPStarterCordova application, https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/quick-start/cordova/, using Xcode iOS simulator. I have set up Xcode and Cordova in my Mac and tested a sample application, FoodTracker, https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/BuildABasicUI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH5-SW1, in Xcode successfully. I opened MFPStarterCordova in Xcode. The application was built successfully, and then, it crashes with error,

2017-01-01 17:14:03.265 MFPStarterCordova[5607:141376] [FATAL] [WORKLIGHT] Uncaught Exception: Could not add the Keychain Item.
libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception
(lldb)

My error is similar to the discussion, https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/175315/mobile-app-using-imf-services-crashes-when-running.html. However, I am testing the application in simulator. I think that it should not require Keychain Sharing entitlement? In any case, I tried to turn on the Keychain Sharing in Capabilities, it failed at “Add the Keychain Sharing feature to your App ID” with error “Signing for “MFPStarterCordova” requires a development team”. In Signing, I changed Team to my Apple ID (Personal Team), then I got error “Failed to create provisioning profile”. To fix this error, it seems that I need to register a iPad/iphone device. I wonder why MFPStarterCodova requires Keychain sharing, when it is executed in simulator? Is it possible to turn off the Keychain sharing requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wonder why MFPStarterCodova requires Keychain sharing, when it is executed in simulator? Is it possible to turn off the Keychain sharing requirement?

Keychain sharing is a new requirement by Apple starting Xcode 8 and iOS 10 for running apps in the iOS Simulator, which is why you also have to enable it for applications using the MobileFirst Foundation SDK.

Comment: I am able to run a simple Cordova app, https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html, in iOS simulator without Keychain sharing though. So this requirement is MobileFirst Foundation SDK  only?

Comment: The SDK requires it.